# O que acham de uma tag [sql-joins]?

Tags: debate, status-pronto, tags

Reparei que temos uma tag [left-join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/left-join) com algumas perguntas, e outra [join](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/join) com apenas uma. Será que não deveríamos ter algo mais geral, como uma tag [sql-joins](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-joins) para todos os tipos de `JOIN`?

Comment: Creio que tudo deveria ser posto na tag `join`, simplesmente. Ou no máximo `sql-join`, no singular. `sql-joins` me soa um tanto estranho, mas é só minha opinião pessoal.

Comment: Concordo com o @mgibsonbr. No meu ver, **[tag:join]** basta.

Comment: Ok, oficializada a tag join. left-join agora é sinônima.

Comment: Convém salientar que existe uma diferença entre fazer `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` ou `INNER JOIN`. Consoante o problema em mãos, a solução pode passar apenas por uma das 3. Com isto pretendo alertar que se usamos uma tag `JOIN` não vamos estar a clarificar devidamente o problema para futuros leitores localizarem a solução já existente.

Comment: Eu acho legal ter apenas a tag join dado o número limitado de questões que precisam da tag atualmente, mas se é pra ter left-join melhor que não seja sinônimo.

Comment: @Zuul Eu acho que basta o detalhamento na pergunta ou resposta para esclarecer isso. O sistema de tags não precisa ser tão específico, não é a único critério considerado nas buscas.

Comment: Acredito que o numero atual de perguntas no site não requeira nem mesmo a tag join. Agrupar tudo sobre SQL na tag SQL e dividir entre os dbs, como MySQL, SQL Servers e afins já é suficiente e correto na demanda atual de perguntas.

Comment: Mas tem muito mais pergunta sobre join sem essa tag específica, @RodrigoBorth. Quando eu tiver tempo, pretendo adicionar a tag em várias perguntas (a não ser que essa sua opinião seja a da maioria e a tag morra antes).

Comment: @bfavaretto acredito que a maioria não vai querer agrupar em uma unica tag. Vendo pelo outro ponto de vista, separar as coisas agora elimina um trabalho futuro. Mas enfim ainda sou da opinião de que não fica legal desagrupar demais as coisas. Acredito que se mantivermos SQL temos que eliminar seus "filhos" e se quisermos os "filhos" devemos eliminar o SQL

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Você pode postar sua opinião como resposta pra chamar a atenção para essa discussão?

Comment: Já já elaboro uma resposta completa @bfavaretto

Answer (score 1):

Na minha opinião a tag principal deveria ser `join` e `sql-join` um sinônimo porque, tecnicamente, JOIN não é exatamente exclusivo de SQL.

Claro que 99% das vezes quem usa está relacionando duas ou mais tabelas em um banco de dados, mas dados podem residir em qualquer lugar além de um banco de dados. E relacionar informações manualmente, como que entre duas ou mais matrizes por exemplo, de certa forma é um tipo de JOIN.

*Just my two cents...*

Comment: Depois de ler essa reposta não vou mais elaborar a minha, nao tinha pensado nessa possibilidade de uso pro `Join`. Acredito que agrupar tudo em Join seja o correto. Vamos eliminar suas filhas

Comment: Agrupar sim, mas não remover as outras variantes, afinal right-join faz uma coisa, left-join outra e por aí vai. Ajuda na sanidade do filtro de pesquisa.

Comment: Não adianta filtra pouca coisa, temos pouco conteudo pra filtra tanto assim, right e left join são coisas diferentes, mas se tivermos essas tags, não precisamos da tag join, pois seria uma sobreposição inutil